# HTML pattern comparison with phpUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have two HTML patterns:

- one is `$expected_html` and
- the other is the actual output `$actual_out` (generated by smarty template).

Now I want to perform the assertion for these two strings. I can not use assertEquals becuase both pattern have a different spacing.

Can anybody provide me a solution / help for this?

Comment: Comparing it as XML (`assertXmlStringEqualsXmlString()`) or creating two DomDocuments and converting them back to HTML may work - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167788/phpunit-asserting-identical-html-structure-regardless-of-whitespace

Answer (score 1):

It's totally depends what exactly the differences are.

Some Guide lines to get it work:

- Try to make both equals by doing some operations on them & than use
  `assertEquals`.

  example:

> // To replace newlines and tabs to match expected one.
>
> $actual_out = str_replace("\n", '',$actual_out);
>
> $actual_out = str_replace("\t", '',$actual_out);

- `assertStringMatchesFormat()` to get match specific
  format(regexp) provided by you.
- Or you can also try to make assert on just critical portion of the strings form of the output.

Comment: Thanks Rikesh, actually problem is that the actual pattern contain irregular white space and tabs.and it is impossible to create same expected pattern ... right now i make assert on just critical portion of the strings form of the output but i want to rid from number of assertions with a new wayout..

Comment: You have to replace that spaces to make them equal. I can understand it's tedious job, though I can't see any other easy way out other than the points I mentioned above.